Pinescript Conundrum [EMA Crossover Strategy]
I'm trying to create an EMA Crossover Strategy in Pinescript but I've run into several issues
The intention is to open long positions during a bullish crossover, and to enter short positions during a bearish crossover
The positions are supposed to remain open until either the SL or TP are hit
Position size: 1 unit
SL: 1 unit
TP: 2 units
My code unfortunately closes trades prematurely more often than not, and I'm struggling to see why that is the case [see attached images]
prematurely closed trades](https://i.sstatic.net/jy0BCJMF.png)
I'm also trying to implement a text-box which displays win rate, profit/loss, and total number of trades
I'm having zero luck with that
One important feature of the code is the stop loss. The stop loss is supposed to be at the most recent swing low or swing high, before the crossover happens [see attached images]
swing low and high example](https://i.sstatic.net/cLQZsRgY.png)
Swing low is defined by the middle candle being lower than the two candles next to it
Swing high is defined by the middle candle being higher than the two candles next to it
Here is my code:
<pre>//@version=5
strategy(title="Backtest Tool", shorttitle="Backtest Tool", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)

// Calculate EMA values
shortEMA = ta.ema(close, 12)
longEMA = ta.ema(close, 26)

// Plot EMAs
plot(shortEMA, color=color.blue, title="EMA 12")
plot(longEMA, color=color.red, title="EMA 26")

// Detect crossover
crossover = ta.crossover(shortEMA, longEMA)
crossunder = ta.crossunder(shortEMA, longEMA)

// Calculate swing highs and lows
swingHigh = ta.highest(high, 3)
swingLow = ta.lowest(low, 3)

// Entry and exit logic
var bool inLongPosition = false
var bool inShortPosition = false
var float entryPriceLong = na
var float entryPriceShort = na
var float winCount = 0
var float lossCount = 0
var float totalTrades = 0
var float totalPL = 0
var float stopLossLong = na
var float stopLossShort = na
var float takeProfitLong = na
var float takeProfitShort = na
var label resultLabel = na

// Calculate stop loss and take profit points
stopLossPoints = 1
takeProfitPoints = 2

// Plot stop loss and take profit markers
plotchar(stopLossLong, "SL", location.belowbar, color=color.red)
plotchar(takeProfitLong, "TP", location.abovebar, color=color.green)
plotchar(stopLossShort, "SL", location.abovebar, color=color.red)
plotchar(takeProfitShort, "TP", location.belowbar, color=color.green)

if crossover
if not inLongPosition
    inLongPosition := true
    entryPriceLong := close
    stopLossLong := swingLow[1] - stopLossPoints * syminfo.mintick
    takeProfitLong := entryPriceLong + takeProfitPoints * syminfo.mintick
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=1)

if crossunder
if not inShortPosition
    inShortPosition := true
    entryPriceShort := close
    stopLossShort := swingHigh[1] + stopLossPoints * syminfo.mintick
    takeProfitShort := entryPriceShort - takeProfitPoints * syminfo.mintick
    strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, qty=1)

if inLongPosition
if low <= stopLossLong
    strategy.close("Long")
    inLongPosition := false
    totalTrades += 1
    lossCount += 1
    totalPL -= stopLossPoints
else if high >= takeProfitLong
    strategy.close("Long")
    inLongPosition := false
    totalTrades += 1
    winCount += 1
    totalPL += takeProfitPoints

if inShortPosition
if high >= stopLossShort
    strategy.close("Short")
    inShortPosition := false
    totalTrades += 1
    lossCount += 1
    totalPL += stopLossPoints
else if low <= takeProfitShort
    strategy.close("Short")
    inShortPosition := false
    totalTrades += 1
    winCount += 1
    totalPL -= takeProfitPoints

// Calculate win rate
winRate = totalTrades > 0 ? (winCount / totalTrades) * 100 : na

// Calculate profit/loss

profitLoss = totalPL
// Combine results into a single string
resultsText = "Win Rate: " + str.tostring(winRate, "#.##") + "% | Profit/Loss: " + str.tostring(profitLoss, "#.##") + " | Trades: " + str.tostring(totalTrades, "#.0")

// Display results in a black box in the upper right corner
var label labResult = na
if barstate.islast
resultLabel := label.new(bar_index, high, text=resultsText, textcolor=color.blue, xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.abovebar, style=label.style_label_down)

else
label.set_text(resultLabel, resultsText)
I tried many methods, but ultimately ended up with something strange. I'm new to Pinescript so I'd definitely appreciate some help 
